# MyISAM vs InnoDB MariaDB for lots of read operations

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb

I have read for years that MyISAM was the preferred DB engine for MySQL/MariaDB when you have a lots of read operations vs lots of insert/update/deletes. I have stuck with MyISAM for tables that are heavy on the SELECT side.

I recently had a about 5 out of 20 tables get corrupted which I could not bring back to life using the various repair methods. Turns out, each table that was corrupted/died was MyISAM. Can't remember if every MyISAM table was corrupted or not. But, none of the InnoDB tables were damaged as far as I can tell.

As I have been eating/breathing and sleeping MariaDB for the last few days working through recovering and improving our database infrastructure (replicas, backups etc), I have noticed that InnoDB is now the default and preferred engine for MariaDB (which wasn't always the case).

I also read that InnoDB tables are much less likely to die a terrible death like mine recently did. When InnoDB tables die, they are easier to recover.

With all that being said, I am seriously considering converting ALL of my remaining MyISAM tables to InnoDB.

My questions are:

1. Should I expect anything to blow up on a live system which relies on these tables (websites, mobile app back ends etc) or is it more likely everything will just keep on chugging after the conversion?
2. When it comes to the performance, is it likely to get better or worse on a system that is heavy on the SELECT side of things? It may still be worth it to convert for future stability of the tables even if there is a small performance hit, I just want to know what I'm in for so I can possibly increase the RAM and CPU resources if needed.
3. Will converting these tables break or changes replication in any way?
4. Final question... Is there really any good reason for me to keep any of my tables in MyISAM these days? It doesn't sound like there is.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with these items.

Comment: "Should I expect anything to blow..." -- not really. and I would tend to think that InnoDB is nowadays much more stable than MyISAM (more dedication, effor, support, etc.). Of course, if you have live apps relying on the current backend, I would test it thoroughly in advance in a separate testing environment.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was always a trade-off between stability and performance. But if you are using MariaDB why not use Aria which is supposed to give you the best of both worlds?

> Should I expect anything to blow on a live system which relies on these tables

Yes - you should always plan for recovery from corruption, ransomware, meteor strikes. InnoDB might be more resillient than MyISAM but it doesn't solve all issues.

> is it likely to get better or worse on a system that is heavy on the SELECT side of things?

erm....it won't be faster. Whether there will be a noticeable drop in performance is a very complicated question and dependent on lots and lots of factors. If you're doing an export/import migration then it should be trivial to go back.

> Will converting these tables break or changes replication in any way?

Only if you try to do the conversion while running replication at the same time.

Do set innodb_file_per_table before the migration.

Comment: Sorry I meant, is it likely that anything will blow up as a result of the migration to InnoDB not in general/ever.

Comment: It is more probable during the conversion than at other times. Likely? No.

Answer (score 0):

If the repeated corruption is not enough incentive to switch away from MyISAM, and the newer benchmarks that usually show InnoDB as being faster even for readonly tables, and the flagging support for MyISAM is not important (especially by MyISAM and any "cluster"), then what can I say?

OTOH, if you have "huge" tables, be aware that InnoDB takes 2x-3x the disk space that MyISAM takes.  (Q4) This *may* be the only defensible argument for keeping a table in MyISAM, at least until you upgrade the disk.

If you are running an "old" version, then certain features may be missing.  For example, `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` were only recently added to InnoDB.

More details on conversion gotchas:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb  And be sure to change `key_buffer_size` (down) and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (up):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

(Q3) Replication will usually work; it is even OK to have different engines for a table on the Primary versus Replica.  Still, there could be some hiccups.  Check `binlog_format`.

(Q2) CPU resources are rarely the bottleneck for MySQL/MariaDB apps.  When it is, there is usually a workaround of building a better index and/or reformulating the query.

Speaking of which, Be aware that InnoDB clusters the PK with the data; this has some impact on choice of indexes.  See, especially, [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .  To improve your indexes, see [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

I agree with setting `innodb_file_per_table = ON` *before* starting the changes.